# Vue v-row and v-col conditional rendering question

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So i have a vuetify template that looks like this

```
<v-row>
 <v-col cols="1"> Text </v-col>
 <v-col cols="1" v-if="condition"> .. </v-col>
 <v-col cols="1" v-if="condition"> .. </v-col>
 <v-col cols="1" v-if="!condition"> .. </v-col>
 <v-col cols="1" v-if="!condition"> .. </v-col>
 <v-col cols="1" v-if="!condition"> .. </v-col>

</v-row>
```

So my question is instead of adding a v-if to all of my v-cols is there a way to group them i tried the following:

```
<v-row>
 <v-col cols="1"> Text </v-col>
 <div v-if="condition>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
 </div>
 <div v-if="!condition>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
 </div>

</v-row>
```

But the div tag changes the UI and displays the v-col's vertically is there a tag i can use for this

Comment: I'm confused with what you're trying to achieve here. Can you give more details please?

Comment: Instead of adding v-if to all my cols i want to group them like in a div tag so i only add the v-if to the div, but div tag changes the UI i need something that does not effect the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can simply use the good 'ole `template` tag like this:

```
 <template v-if="condition>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
 </template>
 <template v-if="!condition>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1"> .. </v-col>
 </template>
```